# The number of elements in $S$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p(x)=a_{1}x^2+a_{2}x+a_{3}$ be a polynomial where  $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3} \in \mathbb{R}$. Fix $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$.Let $$S=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R^{3}} : p(x)=a(x-x_{0})^2+b(x-x_{0})+c \;\text{ for all }\:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$. Then the number of elements in $S$ is.....

I tried with the basis elements $1, x-x_{0}, (x-x_{0})^2$ of $S$ . But didn't get.Please give some hint.

Comment: Did you mean to write "for all $x\in \Bbb R$ and all degree-$2$ polynomials $p(x)$"?

Comment: Why are there braces around "$p(x) = a_1 x^2 + a_2 x + a_3$ be a polynoimal where $a_1,a_2,a_3 \in \Bbb{R}$"?  Do you have the set of all such polynomials, or is $p$ a single, specific polynomial?

Comment: $p(x)$ be second degree polynomial with real coefficients...

Answer (score 1):

The set $S$ is the set of all coordinates $(a,b,c)$ in the space of Real polynomials of degree $\leq 2$ for the polynomial $p$ in the basis $1,x-x_0,(x-x_0)^2$. This is because two polynomials agree everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ iff they are the same polynomial function. But coordinates are necessarily unique, and given by the change of basis formula between the standard basis $1,x,x^2$ and the chosen basis $1,x-x_0,(x-x_0)^2$, so $S$ contains exactly one element.

Answer (score 0):

$a(x-x_0)^2+b(x-x_0)+c=ax^2+(b-2ax_0)x+(ax_0^2-bx_0+c)=a_1x^2+a_2x+a_3$, so we solve for $a,b,c$ by comparison of independent terms.

We necessarily have $a=a_1$, so $b=a_2+2a_1x_0$, and $c=a_3-a_1x_0^2+a_2x_0$.

We have derived a unique solution, so the set is a singleton.

Comment: ,In your(gfppoy) answer, the values of $a = a_1$ but $a_1$ is not a Fixed real number. It takes any real value. So why you said that it is unique. ?